# R saving workspace with save.image() turns tibbles into plain dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

in RStudio, I have around 100 objects mostly tibbles, 5GB total which are always loaded before our analysis workflow.
I'd like to store them all as a single .Rdata or some other appropriate data format so loading them is more convenient and consistent between team members' machine.

combination of
`save.image("~/r_all.Rdata", compress = TRUE)`
and
`load("~/r_all.Rdata")` seemed to work great at first, but then I noticed all tibbles are turned into plain data.frames.
Our codebase is very much reliant on tidyverse and this causes nuisance of having to convert them back to tibbles

Is there a way to store entire workspace where tibbles are kept as tibbles?

Comment: Not reproducible.  `x <- tibble(X=1, Y=2); save.image("./temp.Rdata"); load("./temp.Rdata"); class(x)` gives me `[1] "tbl_df" "tbl" "data.frame"`.  Tidyverse version `1.3.2`, R version `4.2.1`, OS X `10.14.6`.

Comment: I know it doesn't address your exact question, but if you keep all your tibbles in a list you can use a relatively straightforward `lapply()` to write them all to disk (`write_csv()` etc) and easily retrieve them again the next day.  If different team members have their own versions (i.e. you don't need to share and update from day to day) it may even be worth the time to assemble them into a package to just load with a `library()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just a silly oversight on my part!

I thought "tibbles are turned into plain data.frame" because of the way tibbles are printed on console - *I hadn't load tidyverse package* so tibbles are just "printed" as base data.frame would.

run `pacman::p_laod(tidyverse)` and tibbles are printed exactly as expected.

Thank you Limey for pointing that out!